# What type of window is this?

Tags: windows

I have a window in my bedroom that moves up and down with a sort of helical rail.

Its become stuck and in doing a web search on how to get it moving I realized I have no idea what its called.

What type of window is this?

[image: The window rail]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your window type is "double hung" the corkscrew type rod is part of the mechanism called the ballast.

This link will show info on replacement part info.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bwtn4o80S-w

Comment: Thanks! Specifically the terms spiral balance and tilt window from that video and its follow up, "How to replace a tilt window spiral balance", (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkePjaeOsYM) solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tilt-in double hung window.  try using a spray silicone on the sides of the upper and lower stiles for ease of movement.

Comment: There are many different tilt-in sash windows.   spray may work but  an answer specific to this design would be more useful